# Golang, Firebase... converting a MAP to a struct slice

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

how to convert a Document map Snapshot from firestore into a struct slice?  The struct is not displayed in this example, but the problem code is towards the end of the page.

This code works except for the Marked Code at bottom. Code communicates with a FireStore DB and returns a complicated structure called COMPLEX_NONACS.  Bascially, I want to convert . firestore snapshot into a json golang object.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "firebase.google.com/go"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    sa := option.WithCredentialsFile("./scai-qit-fb-adminsdk.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, sa)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
    }
    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    CompNACS := []string{}
    var SCNACS COMPLEX_NONACS // single Complex NONACS
    var MCNACS []COMPLEX_NONACS

    iter := client.Collection("COMPLEX_NONACS").Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to iterate: %v", err)
        }
        //This part works.  WIll return a Map of each Document
        fmt.Println("--------------------------/n")
        fmt.Println(doc.Ref.ID)
        fmt.Println("--/n")
        fmt.Println(doc.Data())

        //  PUT ANSWER HERE...
        // doc.Data() should return map[String] interface{} that is
        // actually of a struct TYPE COMPLEX_NONACS.
        // Question is there a simpler way to CAST doc.Data() as
        // a type?  Docs say this...
        // Data returns the DocumentSnapshot's fields as a map.
        // It is equivalent to
        //     var m map[string]interface{}
        //     d.DataTo(&m)
        // except that it returns nil if the document does not exist.

        //---   this is the error ---
        //  The problem cannot convert to COMPLEX_NONACS  
        SCNACS = COMPLEX_NONACS(doc.Data())
        fmt.Println(SCNACS)

        CompNACS = append(CompNACS, doc.Ref.ID)
    }
}
```

/==========================
the first two Documents...
The structure is the same for all documents in the collection, but some Documents just have different combinations of fields.  I would list the struct, but it is huge.

```
--------------------------/n
A01B01C01D01
--/n
map[E01PCI: DE03CABG:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E06CPCI: DE06CCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE01PCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE06CPCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DF03CABGPCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE05CCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE04PCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE07BPRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] Q04PRIORCABG:No Previous CABG DF03PRIMARY:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] E06BPCI: E05BCABG: E06CCABG: DF04PRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE05APCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] E03PCI: F03CABGPCI: DE06CABG:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE05CPCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] E04PRIMARY: DE05BPCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE04CABG:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] Q03:C01 E06APRIMARY:48-Asymptomatic DE06PCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] F03CABG: E05ACABG: DEADEND: DE04PRIMARY:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E05CPCI: Q01IschemicSymptoms:Asymptomatic (No ischemic symptoms) DE02PCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] INDEX:A01B01C01D01 E05PRIMARY: F01PRIMARY: E01PRIMARY: Q03NonInvasiveTestResults:No non-invasive testing performed E03PRIMARY: DE03PRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] Q02AntiIschemicMedicalTherapy:No Therapy DF04PCI:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DF01PRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] F04PCI: E05CCABG: DE07CCABG:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] E07CCABG: E07PRIMARY:49-Asymptomatic F03PRIMARY: E05CPRIMARY:23-Asymptomatic E07BPRIMARY: E07BCABG: DE06PRIMARY:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DE07CABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DF02PRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE05PRIMARY:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DE06APCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DF03CABG:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E06ACABG: E06BPRIMARY: E07APCI: DE06APRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC:08 SCORE:08 INDICATION:48 SCOREDEFINITIONS:48 Q01CAT:Asymptomatic TermDescription:[48. Three-vessel CAD (no left main) Abnormal LV systolic function -] Name:48-Asymptomatic] DF04CABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E06APCI: E02PCI: E05PCI: DE07ACABG:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E04CABG: DE05ACABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DE07APRIMARY:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE06BCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] F04CABG: Q02:B01 DE07PRIMARY:map[TermDescription:[49. Left main stenosis  -] Name:49-Asymptomatic SCOREGRAPHIC:09 SCORE:09 INDICATION:49 SCOREDEFINITIONS:49 Q01CAT:Asymptomatic] DE07PCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E06PCI: DE06BPRIMARY:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] E02PRIMARY:20-Asymptomatic DE06ACABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DE05BCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E07CABG: DE07CPRIMARY:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE05BPRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC:03 SCORE:03 INDICATION:22 SCOREDEFINITIONS:22 Q01CAT:Asymptomatic TermDescription:[22. One- or 2-vessel CAD with borderline stenosis 50% to 60% No noninvasive testing performed or equivocal test results present FFR less than or equal to 0.80* and/or IVUS with significant reduction in] Name:22-Asymptomatic] E02CABG: E04PCI: DE05APRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE05CPRIMARY:map[SCORE:01 INDICATION:23 SCOREDEFINITIONS:23 Q01CAT:Asymptomatic TermDescription:[23. One- or 2-vessel CAD with borderline stenosis 50% to 60% No noninvasive testing performed or equivocal test results present FFR or IVUS findings do not meet criteria for significant stenosis] Name:23-Asymptomatic SCOREGRAPHIC:01] DE07BCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E01CABG: E05BPCI: E05BPRIMARY:22-Asymptomatic DE07CPCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE02PRIMARY:map[Q01CAT:Asymptomatic TermDescription:[20. One- or 2-vessel CAD without involvement of proximal LAD No noninvasive testing performed -] Name:20-Asymptomatic SCOREGRAPHIC:03 SCORE:03 INDICATION:20 SCOREDEFINITIONS:201] DE01CABG:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] Q01:A01 E03CABG: E06PRIMARY: DE06CPRIMARY:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE06BPCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE02CABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DF04CABGPCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] F02PRIMARY: E05APCI: E07APRIMARY: F04PRIMARY: E05CABG: E06CPRIMARY: E06CABG: DE07APCI:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] Q04:D01 DE01PRIMARY:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E07CPRIMARY: F04CABGPCI: E07CPCI: E05APRIMARY: DE05PCI:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DF03PCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] F03PCI: E07ACABG: DE05CABG:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] Title:NACS-100 DE03PCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] E07BPCI: E07PCI: DE07BPCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] E06BCABG:]
--------------------------/n
A01B01C01D02
--/n
map[DF03PCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] F04PRIMARY: DEADEND:NR DE05CPRIMARY:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DE05CPCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE07BPCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] F02PRIMARY: DE07CPRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE07CABG:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E02PRIMARY: DE05BCABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] E01PCI: Q03NonInvasiveTestResults:No non-invasive testing performed E07BPRIMARY: E06CPCI: E03PRIMARY: E06CCABG: E06APRIMARY: E07PCI: DE05BPCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E01CABG: DE05CCABG:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DF04CABGPCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE07ACABG:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E04CABG: DE05PCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE07APCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E05CABG: INDEX:A01B01C01D02 E04PCI: DE07CPCI:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E06PCI: E05CCABG: F03PRIMARY: F04CABGPCI: E05APCI: E05BPRIMARY: DE06CPCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DF03CABGPCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:[] Name:69 SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:69 SCOREDEFINITIONS:] E07CPCI: DE06APCI:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE05ACABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE05APRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE06BPCI:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DF04CABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE03PCI:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE07CCABG:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE06ACABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] F03PCI: DE06PRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E07CABG: E05BCABG: DE06BCABG:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] F03CABGPCI:69 DE06BPRIMARY:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] F04CABG: E05PRIMARY: Title:NACS-500 DE07APRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E06ACABG: E03PCI: DE02CABG:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE06CPRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] DE07BPRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] F01PRIMARY: DE01PCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE06APRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E07APCI: DE06CABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DE07BCABG:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DF02PRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E04PRIMARY: DF04PRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE05PRIMARY:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] E06CPRIMARY: Q02AntiIschemicMedicalTherapy:No Therapy E06PRIMARY: E01PRIMARY: Q04PRIORCABG:Previous CABG E05CPCI: DF01PRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E07APRIMARY: E06BPRIMARY: E05CPRIMARY: DE03PRIMARY:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] E06CABG: E03CABG: DE02PCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] F03CABG: E05APRIMARY: DF04PCI:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE05CABG:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] DE05APCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] E02PCI: Q01IschemicSymptoms:Asymptomatic (No ischemic symptoms) E07PRIMARY: DE04CABG:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] E06APCI: E06BCABG: DE02PRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] DE06PCI:map[INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE:] DF03CABG:map[SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC:] DE07PCI:map[SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION:] Q03:C01 E05PCI: DE06CCABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DE04PCI:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E07BCABG: E07CPRIMARY: E02CABG: DE03CABG:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] F04PCI: E07ACABG: DE04PRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] Q04:D02 E05BPCI: E07CCABG: DE05BPRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] DF03PRIMARY:map[Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS:] DE01PRIMARY:map[SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil> Name:] E05ACABG: Q01:A01 E07BPCI: DE01CABG:map[TermDescription:<nil> Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT:] Q02:B01 DE07PRIMARY:map[Name: SCOREGRAPHIC: SCORE: INDICATION: SCOREDEFINITIONS: Q01CAT: TermDescription:<nil>] E06BPCI:]
```

Comment: Please post the output of doc.Data(dummy) to check its structure so that we can store it inside golang struct.

Comment: OK... I just added two documents from the output and explanation.  There has got to be a simpler way to marshal these maps into the struct than doing each field individually.

Comment: What to the structs look like? How many fields are there? Are the fields simple primitive types or complex, nested types?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting result data from Firebase with type `map[string]interface{}` and you need to convert it to type `map[string]*Foo` (where `Foo` is some struct defined elsewhere).

If the `Foo` struct can easily be de/serialized into some intermediate format then you might be able to serialize the untyped values and then deserialize them into a variable of your desired type.

For example, using JSON ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/M8YC7ZtfKGP)):

```
docdata := getDocData()
for label, data := range docdata {
    // Marshal the untyped data into a suitable format.
    bs, err := json.Marshal(data)
    check(err)
    // Unmarshal the formatted data into a variable with desired type.
    var foo *Foo
    err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &foo)
    check(err)
    fmt.Printf("OK: label=%q, foo=%#v\n", label, foo)
}
// OK: label="E01PCI", foo=(*main.Foo)(nil)
// OK: label="E06CPCI", foo=(*main.Foo)(nil)
// OK: label="DE03CABG", foo=&main.Foo{Name:"Alpha", SCOREGRAPHIC:"Bravo", SCORE:3.14159, INDICATION:true, SCOREDEFINITIONS:"Echo", Q01CAT:6, TermDescription:(*string)(nil)}
// OK: label="DE06CCABG", foo=&main.Foo{Name:"Hotel", SCOREGRAPHIC:"India", SCORE:10.1, INDICATION:true, SCOREDEFINITIONS:"Lima", Q01CAT:13, TermDescription:(*string)(0x1050c3d0)}
```

It's unclear from your question whether the data in `doc.Data()` is the entire struct that you mention or some other sort of structured data which includes instances of your struct (my example assumes the latter); however, the general idea of serializing into an intermediate format and deserializing into a typed variable should work either way.